# SQL Join Duplicating Totals in Certain Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Trying to join two tables, to display matching totals, however the join (or group by) is creating incorrect summations for a few records (not all). I checked both tables separately to ensure paid+tax matches total, and they do when viewed in separate tables. What appears to be happening is a few of the "total1" records are being multiplied by 2 (no idea why).

Table1:

| pnum | branch | year | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | efgh | 2018 | 2000 |
| 5678 | efgh | 2018 | 2579 |

Table2:

| pnum | branch | year | paid | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | efgh | 2018 | 3200 | 900 |
| 5678 | efgh | 2018 | 400 | 79 |

Code:

```
Select pnum, a.branch, a.year, sum(total) as total, sum(paid+tax) as total1
from ##table1 a
inner join ##table2 b

on a.[pnum] = b.pnum2 and a.year = left(b.year,4) and a.branch = b.branch
Group by pnum, a.branch, a.year
```

The outcome looks something like this:

| pnum | branch | year | total | total1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | abcd | 2020 | 3520 | 3520 |
| 5678 | efgh | 2018 | 4579 | 9158 |
| 9101 | ijkl | 2019 | 2378 | 2378 |
| 1121 | mnop | 2019 | 9436 | 9436 |

As you can see, in row 2, the "total1" is double the "total" value...both "total" and "total1" should match.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data.  It is not obvious that the results are incorrect.

Comment: Hi @2020db9 please check paid and tax column value for row 2. May be wrong value exists.

Comment: Most likely one of the tables has a duplicate row, probably `##table2`. Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: Develop good habits. Every column reference should include the appropriate table alias (and alias names like "a" are just lazy habits too). We don't know which table contains which column, but your logic appears to assume that there is a 1:1 relationship between the tables. Otherwise there would be no "duplicates" and your totals would be correct. You might be able to UNION ALL the tables and then sum that resultset - but that is a risky guess without DDL and sample data.

Comment: could is be an issue with the sum(paid+tax) ?

I edited my initial post and included examples of the source data

Comment: I see you've added sample data for pnum=1234/branch=abcd, but you need to add sample data for an output row that has an unexpected result, so your pnum=5678/branch=efgh rows would be good, and it needs to be all the relevant rows so we can compare the totals.

Comment: @EdmCoff 
I can do that, so for Table2: pnum=5678/branch=efgh/year=2018/paid=4000/tax=579
                                 Table1: pnum=5678/branch=efgh/year=2018/total=4579

I also checked for duplicates and their are none, I'm wondering if the issue is somewhere in the summation of Total1

Comment: With that sample data, you do not get the result you posted. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90735fc8f6efc886c6f66a1b2b9ff5c8 You need to provide the actual data and the actual query you are using.

Comment: I modified the above source tables, in the initial post, to give you a better idea (for this particular pnum). As mentioned, it's not occurring with every pnum which makes it even more confusing. I'm thinking maybe I need to sum total1 prior to the join, but am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal join behavior when the relationship is not one to one.  You possibly have more than one match in each table.  You can do this several ways.  Here's one which sums each table separately and then joins the result.  This relationship (between cte1 and cte2) is now one to one.  I'm ignoring cases in which entries in one table might not have matches in the other.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT pnum, branch, year, SUM(total) AS total1
          FROM table1
         GROUP BY pnum, branch, year
     )
   , cte2 AS (
        SELECT pnum2 AS pnum, branch, year, SUM(paid+tax) AS total2
          FROM table2
         GROUP BY pnum2, branch, year
     )
SELECT cte1.pnum, cte1.branch, cte1.year, cte1.total1, cte2.total2
  FROM cte1
  JOIN cte2
    ON cte1.pnum   = cte2.pnum
   AND cte1.branch = cte2.branch
   AND cte1.year   = cte2.year
;
```

The final corrected result:

```
pnum    branch  year    total1  total2
5678    efgh    2018    4579    4579
```

The test case provided by @EdmCoff was helpful.  I adjusted that to show your reported behavior and then added a solution at the bottom of the fiddle.

[Working test case, edited from the comment of @EdmCoff](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff76034030bdfaea8645117f82d79b14)

Notice that @EdmCoff created an initial testcase which avoided the problem by manually aggregating the table data before inserting.  That is essentially what we did in the final solution, in each CTE term.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a join use `UNION ALL` to get all the rows of the 2 tables and then aggregate:

```
SELECT pnum, branch, year,
       SUM(total) total,
       SUM(total1) total1
FROM(
  SELECT pnum, branch, year, total, 0 total1 FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pnum2, branch, LEFT(year, 4), 0, paid + tax FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY pnum, branch, year
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4223812e37738b42ebd87734ce9f7a84).